# CLLocation not updating in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

I implement the following code in viewDidLoad

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and i try to get my location every second via

```
 CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
 NSLog(@"[%f,%f]",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
```

i try to set the custom location in the iOS simulator, but the location never get updated,
i had also tried it on my iphone device and it seems it only capture the first location and subsequent location is not been updated.

Please advise me on how to resolve it

Comment: Does your location get changed when you select in the IOS Simulator -> Debug -> Location -> City Bike Ride?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to get continuous updated latitude and longitude

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{  
    CLLocation *location_updated = [locations lastObject];   
    NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);
}
```